# Combo box data source binding doesn't show text when data is updated in data grid view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, combobox

I have bound a data grid view and a combo box to my table (which is managed by Entity Framework):

```
eraDataGridView.DataSource = BillContext.Eras.Local.ToBindingList();
eraComboBox.DataSource = BillContext.Eras.Local.ToBindingList();
eraComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

and I have created a save button for the data grid view:

```
private void saveEras_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BillContext.SaveChanges();
    saveEras.Enabled = false;
}
```

When I insert a new row to the data grid view; if I select another row after I finish editing the row (by clicking on another row, pressing tab or enter) and then click on the save button everything works as expected, but if I press the save button without changing the row; the combo box will have a new item without text(which is the new row but without the text).

How can I make the combo box show the text of the newly added row in the described scenario? Any workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: If you create a new row, but don't change it, then it will represent a new, but empty item, that will be obviously shown in the `ComboBox` exactly as it is - as an empty value. Or am I missing something? If you want to avoid such behaviour, then you should somehow filter and remove such empty items from underlying collection in the `saveEras_click` handler before saving the changes. Also you may try some wrapper collection that will filter these items for ComboBox, but empty items will still get to the DB.

Comment: i thought it was obvious but in the scenario that i described i do change the row but showing an empty text or showing the text that i wrote depends on selecting another row after the edit or not selecting another row and saving

Comment: Perhaps your items do not implement INotifyProperyChanged?

Comment: i'm not sure, i'm using System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox and System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView. what should i do?

Comment: [INotifyProperyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) allows changes in an item to be seen by all bound controls. `BindingList` just allows to detect and notify about changes in collections of items, but if one individual item is modified and it doesn't implement `INotifyProperyChanged` then barring full collection/binding reloading no one else will see it or react to it. Most probably your EF entities by default do not implement it.

Comment: implementing INotifyPropertyChanged solves my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my DAO classes solves this problem.
[more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)